# Set multiple fonts in UILabel with NSMutableAttributedString not working

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, uifont

I'm trying to create attribute string with 2 fonts first is normal and second is bold.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10.0] range:firstRange];
[str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:10.0] range:secondRange];
```

But It's show all text with normal text. I'm sure range is not the same.
How can I make it show normal and bold in 1 label.

Comment: Could you log `str` and check that's it is correct (you can see if there are two fonts). Also, do you correctly do `[myLabel setAttributedText:str]` and not `[myLabel setText:[str string]];`? Because your code doesn't seems wrong, but the issue could be after. And also, that you don't do `[myLabel setFont:someFont]`?

Comment: Show the code where you are getting this range.

Comment: @Larme I have logged "str" is look good. nothing wrong. I have changed from font to colour and it work fine. Is it possible to do this?.

Comment: @Nirav    Here is my code || 

    NSRange firstRange = NSMakeRange(0, content.length);
    NSRange secondRange = NSMakeRange(content.length-1, message.length-content.length)

Comment: The log of `str` shows the Bold font part? Could you show where you assign `str` to the label?

Comment: @Larme Here is my code `[label setAttributedText:attributeText];`

Comment: `He{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa6dbab89c0> font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 10.00pt";
}llo, World{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fa6dbab0b80> font-family: \"Helvetica Neue\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 15.00pt";
}` This is log from "str"

Comment: `str` is correct (except that in your snippet, it should be 15 for the bold part).

Comment: @Larme issue fixed with my fault. I have used UILabel as my class. And I set appearance. so that's why it's not work. Thanks all!